# Trying to implement jPlayer using jQuery Mobile - player stops when launching dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-mobile, jplayer

I am trying to design a page for mobile devices using jQuery Mobile that has jPlayer on the main page, and other content loaded either in tabs or another page or a dialog, such that the audio in jPlayer keeps playing.

I am not sure how to implement tabs using jQuery Mobile, but I have tried adapting the 2 page example from the demos, and also a single page with a dialog which contains extra content, and using both methods the playback in jPlayer stops.

I am not sure why this is happening.  In the standard webpage I have designed using jPlayer and lightboxes, the lightboxes don't effect the playback in jPlayer, so I was hoping that it would be the same using jQuery Mobile.

To test on an iPhone you will need to tap on a track to get audio playing.

I'd be grateful for any help in getting this working,

Thanks,

Nick

You can see the current page [here](http://monthlymixup.com/iphone.php).  The code between the body tags is:

```
<body> 

<div class="jp-audio">
<div class="jp-type-playlist">
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
    <div id="jp_interface_1" class="jp-interface">
        <div class="jp-video-play"></div>
        <ul class="jp-controls">
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1">mute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1">unmute</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
            <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
    <div id="jp_playlist_1" class="jp-playlist">
        <ul>
            <!-- The method Playlist.displayPlaylist() uses this unordered list -->
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
    </script>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="playlist" data-position="fixed">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Playlist</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#comments">comments</a></p>
            <a href="#comments" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">open dialog</a></p>         

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="comments">



    <div data-role="content">   
                <p><a href="#playlist">Back to playlist</a></p>

    <div id="disqus_thread">
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
          var disqus_shortname = 'monthlymixup'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

          // The following are highly recommended additional parameters. Remove the slashes in front to use.
          var disqus_identifier = 'test';
          var disqus_title = 'the marvelous monthly mix up';
          // var disqus_url = 'http://example.com/permalink-to-page.html';

          /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
          (function() {
              var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
              dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
              (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
          })();
      </script>
      <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>           

                </div><!-- /content -->


</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

here is the script I currently have for showing and hiding pages:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
if($(this).hasClass('haveaplayer'))
   {
   $(.jp-audio).show();
   }else{
   $(.jp-audio).hide();
   }
})
</script>`

and the html:

`<div data-role="page" id="playlist" class="haveaplayer">`

Comment: I have now included code in my original post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code it's just a tip, but it looks like jPlayer doesn't want to be hidden.

The easy answer is to add a `div` element out of the `data-role="page"` div (simply inside the body) and put the jPlayer in there. It will need some extra CSS to display properly (or not be hidden under JQM header:) ) but the jPlayer should work well then.

[edit]

You can try to move the jPlayer between pages with:

```
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pageshow',function(){
  //test if the page should have the player and then:
  $(jPlayerWrapperSelector).appendTo($(this));
})
```

try with `pageshow` and `pagebeforeshow`

If this doesn't work (moving the node can break jPlayer as well) then you can just bind to the page event and hide jPlayer when necessary.

```
$("div:jqmData(role='page')").live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
  //test if the page should have the player and then:
   {
   $(jPlayerWrapperSelector).show();
   }else{
   $(jPlayerWrapperSelector).hide();
   }
})
```

[edit2]

I suggest an if statement like that:

```
if($(this).hasClass('haveaplayer'))
```

You then have to add the class to divs that should have a player. Like this:

```
<div data-role="page" class="haveaplayer">
```

Comment: Thanks, putting the jPlayer code outside of the data-role="page" div does work, but then there is the issue of the top of the player being hidden as you mention, which it sounds like I could fix with CSS, but also more crucially the player then shows on the 'comments' page/tab as well, which I'd rather not have.  I have included the code above and a link to the page with the current implementation (with the jPlayer code outside the data-role="page" div).  On a standard browser jPlayer kept playing when other pages/tabs were loaded, but not on the iPhone.

Comment: That's more of a jPlayer's problem. I'd suggest redoing the playback yourself so that it's simpler and more customized for iphone, but you probably don't want to... Then it's a matter of a nice trick I recently created ;) See edit

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like the extra code you have posted is designed to work with the solution where I put the jPlayer code outside of the data-role="page" div.  The script you have included would then hide the jPlayer on the Comments page.  Have I got this right?  If so, when I added the first script, trying both `pageshow` and `pagebeforeshow`, it broke the page.  Adding the second script doesn't break the page, but doesn't seem to make any difference to what shows and what doesn't show.  Probably I have to add some other code to make this work, for jPlayerWrapperSelector?

Comment: Well yes... I didn't want to guess what you wish to hide, si I put a silly name where a selector for jPlayer should be. If you want me to guess, I'd say you want `#jquery_jplayer` as your selector.
Also: did you see that you have to replace the comment with an `if` statement that decides if the page should have a jPlayer, or did you just copy the pseudocode and expect it to work? ;)

Comment: Thanks for your patience naugtur.  I can be a bit dumb when it comes to javascript.  The code for jPlayer playlist has changed a bit from my original post, and the overall wrapper is now `<div class="jp-audio">` so I changed the selector to `.jp-audio`.  I then added an if statement in place of the comment.  At the moment it is `if(id='playlist')`, but this doesn't work, so I must have got this wrong!

Comment: the if statement should check if the page that is being loaded should have the player visible. You are comparing an undefined variable to a string. This can't work. See edit2

Comment: Thanks again naugtur.  I tried your suggestion, and it still isn't hiding the playlist on the comments page.  I have amended the html for the jPlayer playlist, and included the script and html for hiding the playlist as it currently stands at the bottom of my original post.  I have tried using both 'pageshow' and 'pagebeforeshow'

Comment: no wonder it doesnt't work if you do $(.sth) instead of $('.sth'). There might be more problems, I didn't read it through

Comment: thanks.  that works now.  The transition between pages is a bit clunky, but it does work.  I am in communication with the developer of jPlayer to try to work out what the issue is with jPlayer stopping playing when other 'pages' are displayed.  sorry again for being rather slow with the javascript.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  The script works in as much as it does hide the jPlayer when the 'comments' 'page' loads, but once again, jPlayer stops playing (I must have had it on silent when I tested before!).  I have had further info from the developer of jPlayer who told me to put just the jPlayer DIV: `<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>` outside of data-role="page", between the body tags, and the rest of the html, for the playlist and controls, in one of the 'pages'.  This works fine.  Thanks again for your help.  It got me, and the developer, thinking along the right lines!